# How stored procedure run in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have noticed the following but unable to understand why.

Whenever a procedure is called in .net it takes more time than when it is called subsequently.

Even if a procedure is called after some interval it takes more time than it takes if it is called quite frequently. i am not asking about sql query or sql command. any user definded function or user defined method takes much more time to finish when it is called occasionaly. but when the same procedure is called quite often it finishes a lot faster. why?

what is the reason, can any body help.

Answer (score 2):

In .NET languages the code you write is compiled into Common Intermediate Language (CIL, or just IL for short) bytecode. The JIT compiler on the machine then converts that CIL into native instructions at runtime. So, if you're on an x86 machine, the JIT compiler converts the CIL bytecode into x86 assembly instructions and executes them.

In order to speed up execution, the JIT compiler caches the compiled native code for a short while. When your code leaves the scope of some code and doesn't return to it for a while, the cache entry is removed.

When you run a method repeatedly with only small amounts of time between each call, the native code remains cached and does not need to be recompiled. If you don't call it frequently, the cache entry expires and the code requires a recompilation.

All of this is highly dependant on which .NET runtime you are using, since there is no standardised behaviour behind it.